# php non-english character using $echo

Tags: php

in Php, I want to print **Düsseldorf** using

```
 echo 'Düsseldorf';
```

However it turns out to be something like this **D�sseldorf**

Please suggest what should I do to print european characters mostly non-english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to specify it as a constant, do the following.

```
$echo 'D&#252;sseldorf';
```

For further information refer to the chart here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Every character that's printable has a corresponding HTML entity.

Comment: That's possible but not really a good way for that. First you could better use &uuml; (for ü, &ouml; for ö and so on) but its easier to change the encoding

Comment: No it's not easier to change the encoding, based upon the users local encoding it may not be supported. Encoding should not matter, data and design separate, means it should work in any environment with any backend, not cross your fingers and hope the encoding is compatible.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP, File and HTML encoding should be the same.

For PHP:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Check the encoding of your text editor.

For HTML:

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
```

The quick and dirty way:

```
echo 'D&uuml;sseldorf ist eine sch&oouml;ne Stadt!';
// Düsseldorf ist eine schöne Stadt!
```

Comment: Yes, but I would always recommend utf-8. It's more common, even in Germany.

Comment: I am from Germany too^^ actually I thought ISO-8859-1 is more common here but I often also use UTF-8...

Comment: It was I think :). php 5.4's default charset is utf-8, therefore we should go with them.